# Using xargs and sed to reprocess avi files

Tags: bash, sed, find, xargs

I have a bunch of AVI's that I'd like to reprocess to h264 MKVs.  The command I'm trying to use is:

```
find . -name "*.avi" | xargs -I '{}' ffmpeg -i {} -vcodec libx264 `echo {} | sed 's/avi/mkv/'`
```

However, it does not work as expected. Adding -t to xargs shows that the command being run is (given a directory with file1.avi)

```
ffmpeg ./file1.avi -vcodec libx264 ./file1.avi
```

I'm not sure why the sed command isn't getting processed correctly. ffmpeg fails because it does not overwrite by default.

The AVIs are all in sub-directories so I don't really want to do a for loop for each subfolder and find / xargs would be a much better solution. Also, I don't really want to rename everything after this is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this is not working is because everything between `` ` ` `` is executed before the `xargs` execution. But if you quote it in `' '`, then it is going to be passed correctly, but `xargs` is not going to parse or expand it.

But you can pipe to the bash function!

```
convertFile() {
    while read -r filename; do
        newFilename="${filename:0:-3}mkv"
        ffmpeg "$filename" -vcodec libx264 "$newFilename"
    done
}

find . -name "*.avi" | convertFile
```

Please note that instead of `sed` I am using bash string manipulations. The reason for that is that your file can sometimes contain **avi** word inside, like *gr***avi***ty*. That is why more fail-proof way was used.

Comment: While I like the one liner examples I'm going to say I like this more. Only because it reminds me that I can pre-define functions in ~/.bashrc for repeated tasks.

Answer (score 1):

```
find *.avi | while read f; do
    ffmpeg "$f" -vcodec libx264 "${f%.avi}.mkv"
done
```

and i split the lines to not scare people, but in real life it'd be

```
find *.avi|while read f;do ffmpeg "$f" -vcodec libx264 "${f%.avi}.mkv"; done
```

because this is one-liner territory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command instead :

```
find *.avi | awk '{print "\""$0"\"", "-vodec libx264","\""$0"\""}'  | sed 's/\(.*\)avi\"$/\1mkv\"/g' | xargs ffmpeg -i
```

Of course this has a lot of escape characters. It isn't a script, it's a command-line...

Comment: This is not going to work if a file is named ``miyavi.avi``. Also this does not work for files that have spaces in their name.

Comment: Sure. Usually I don't place neg. votes, but your answer was dangerous. It might work in the test environment and maybe it works with most of the files, but someday it will definitely break! I voted to protect other users from a disaster. Now you've edited it(thanks!) and seems like the problem is gone, but the code has too much bloat now, I can't verify that it works. Also, when I saw your edit I tried to negate my negative vote by clicking UP but it gave you +1 instead of 0, so I clicked back. I should've clicked -1 again to negate it. It is locked now, I can't do anything. I'm still new here

Comment: I guess we have to wait until that day :-) ... I guess it is locked until I edit my answer. I just edited... Try the re-negation.

Comment: Given one result, this works fine, however with more than one it is returning: `ffmpeg -i test1.avi -vcodec libx264 test1.mkv test2.avi -vcodec libx264 test2.mkv test3.avi -vcodec libx264 test3.mkv`